# Ler código de barras ITF boleto brasileiro (tamanho 44) com o plugin BarcodeScanner da phonegap para IOS

Tags: ios, apache-cordova

Alguém conseguiu resolver o problema de leitura de código de barras ITF (tamanho 44) do plugin da PhoneGap "BarcodeScanner"?

O plugin implementado para Android funciona perfeitamente tanto para código de barras grandes e pequenos do ITF. Entretanto o plugin feito para o IOS lê apenas códigos ITF de tamanho pequeno.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Provavelmente se você aumentar a qualidade da captura de imagem para Alta vai funcionar. Deve ser o mesmo problema que enfrentei usando a lib ZBar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32499/ler-c%C3%B3digo-de-barras-de-boleto-banc%C3%A1rio/39074#39074

Comment: o barcode apenas lê o código, e não calcula o digito verificador do código
segue alguns links para estudos http://www.jrimum.org/bopepo/wiki/Componente/Documentacao/Negocio
http://carlosfprocha.com/blogs/paleo/archive/2013/06/21/linha-digit-225-vel-de-boletos-banc-225-rios.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte plugin: https://github.com/dealrinc/cordova-gmv-barcode-scanner

Nele você passa o parâmetro `{ ITF: true }` ao chamar o método `scan`.