# Ler código de barras de boleto bancário

Tags: ios, objective-c, código-de-barras

Como posso ler código de barras de boleto ITF (tamanho 44) codificada no padrão Intercalado 2 de 5. Usando alguma biblioteca como zxing, zbar, etc.?

Ja utilizei as bibliotecas zxing e zbar, mas não reconhece o código de barras do boleto.

Ja tenteis os exemplos:

https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

De todos os exemplos que encontro eu consigo ler todos os tipos de código de barras (QR Code, Code 39, 93, 128, ITF, etc) até os ITF de tamanho pequeno. Menos o de boleto bancário.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

Comment: Não tenho iOS mas me parece que para conseguir depende de uma câmera com resolução alta.

Comment: FYI: Meu voto foi de ampla demais e nao fora de escopo. E além disso, tinha voto de "não é claro". Tou achando que em algum momento vai ser necessário um post no meta explicando o que é cada coisa.

Comment: @Bacco http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216192/167534, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/167534

Comment: @bfavaretto Ótimos links, precisamos de tradutores voluntários :)

Comment: @Bacco eu posso traduzir, só me manda um link de onde postar :D

Comment: @RodrigoBorth no [meta].

Comment: o barcode apenas lê o código, e não calcula o digito verificador do código segue alguns links para estudos http://www.jrimum.org/bopepo/wiki/Componente/Documentacao/Negocio http://carlosfprocha.com/blogs/paleo/archive/2013/06/21/linha-digit-225-vel-de-boletos-banc-225-rios.aspx

Answer (score 5):

É possivel ler código de barra de boletos Brasileiros com a biblioteca ZBar. O que você tem que fazer é setar a qualidade do vídeo para alta. Segue o trecho de código de configuração do ZBarReaderViewController.

```
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
reader.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;


ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here
[scanner setSymbology: 0
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];
```

Desde a versão 7 do iOS o framework AVFoundation oferece um método nativo para leitura de código de barra. Porem, o suporte ao padrão intercalado 2 de 5 (`AVMetadataObjectTypeInterleaved2of5Code`) foi [introduzido recentemente no iOS 8](http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7).

Modifiquei o exemplo disponibilizado [neste tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial) e realmente funciona bem para ler os códigos de barra de boletos tanto título quando convênio.